# Copying millions of files

Tags: file

I've got about 3 million files I need to copy from one folder to another over my company's SAN. What's the best way for  me to do this?

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: No, you're right. I guess it's not. Should I remove it?

Comment: No. leave it.  The nuances of making this happen quickly are computer-sciency enough that the issue could reasonably be considered relevant to programming.

Comment: Are you talking about keeping two large collections of documents in sync (in which case take a look at the discussion of rsync below) or doing a one-off operation?

Comment: both actually - this has been pretty valuable info for me

Comment: I was tempted to close it as non-programming question, but it can be solved by a program, I suppose, so I see it on the limit.
You should update your question to indicate the system(s) and the synch need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on windows, use robocopy. It's very robust and build for situations like that. It supports dead link detection and can be told to retry copies if one is interrupted.

Answer (score 8):

If a straight copy is too slow (although a SAN with write-back caching would be about as fast as anything for this type of operation) you could tar the files up into one or more archives and then expand the archives out at the destination.  This would slightly reduce the disk thrashing.

At a more clever level, you can do a trick with tar or cpio where you archive the files and write them to stdout which you pipe to another tar/cpio process to unravel them at their destination.

A sample command to do this with tar looks like:

```
tar cf - * | (cd [destination dir] ; tar xf - )
```

Some SANs will also directly clone a disk volume.

Comment: +1 on "TAR it up". Especially if you're working with lots of tiny files that will help a lot.

Comment: That tar command can be rewritten as: tar -C <source-dir> cf - . | tar -C <dest-dir> xf -

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/)?  This is a tool that uses an [algorithm that involves calculating hashes on chunks of the files](http://www.samba.org/rsync/tech_report/node2.html) to compare two sites and send deltas between the sites.

Comment: rsync will only get you a benefit if some of the files already exist at the destination and the destination is a different machine.  It would be a win if you had to periodically refresh from one machine to another but won't help for an initial copy.

Comment: It also won't help you much for copying files from one location on a filesystem on the same machine to another.

Comment: @NXC: rsync copies between two folders regardless of whether they're on the same machine or not. It doesn't care.

Comment: It doesn't get you any benefit on the same machine (or anywhere) unless you are synchronising two collections.  The expensive part of this operation is the disk writes.

Comment: Yes, but its easy, and the OP didn't say whether it would have to be copied more than once.

Comment: rsync is slower than a direct copy if the network is faster than 100MB.   rsync w/ compression is faster than a straight copy w/ compression or a plain copy at lower speeds.  http://www.zib.de/schuett/nsync/

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) is in my experience very good at handling ridiculous numbers of files. And it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Teracopy will do this I think.

http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php

Or, if on *nix, try cuteftp.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me, its just the best way to copy with neatest system software.

Just something like:

```
cp -pvr /pathtoolddir /pathtonewdir
```

on a linux box will do and work great. Any compression in between will just slow down the process.